# Nvidia Quadro vs GeForce Features/Technologies

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

I was looking at Quadro graphics cards like the P5000, which I'll probably get for work, but I'd also like to play heavy-duty games on it, but something bugs me about that...

I was looking at the Technologies/Features webpage(image at the link below) on the GeForce website. There's a host of features/technologies that GeForce cards support and most of them have to do with improving gaming. But I wonder if similar Quadros support these same things...there's no Quadro Technologies page like there is for GeForce to easily find the answer to this confusion.

[GeForce Technologies/Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvqmk.jpg)

No matter how deep I try to dig, I can't seem to find any info on whether Quadros, based on the same chips as GeForces(eg. P5000 is based on the same GP104 chip as GTX 1070 is based on) support the same technologies/features, aside from the really generic ones like CUDA, Stereo 3D, VR Support and Optimus technologies. I know Quadros have some of their own features, like Nvidia Mosaic, but does anyone know if they also support the features that their GeForce counterparts support(eg. if a GeForce based on some chip supports Adaptive V-Sync, ShadowWorks, HairWorks, MXAA, DSR, etc, does a Quadro based on the same chip support these technologies as well)?

I can't seem to find answers to this anywhere...is there something really obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: It’s all about support and certifications. // Most of the features you list are not hardware features at all.

Comment: Yes, that's why it's such a hard task to find out what's supported. If they were all hardware features, I'd be pretty sure the features would be more or less the same over all cards based on the same chips(and they are, the ones that are somewhat hardware-related, such as CUDA and Optimus). But what I'm wondering about is if features like HairWorks and ShadowWorks are supported there, as that's most likely a software/driver-related thing...

Comment: 'word on the street' has always been, don't buy Quadros for gaming, they come up much slower than their GeForce equivalents.

Comment: The "word on the street" has been showen multiple times to be inaccurate at best and completely wrong at worst. Same costing Quadros will run slower-because a Quadro costing the same as some GeForce is a few generations older...

If you get a Quadro based on a same chip as some GeForce, then it will basically be the same, raw performance-wise. There's just no way the same chip could do so much better, just because of some extra GeForce driver features.

I'm talking about Quadro P5000 vs GeFroce 1070, both for laptops. It's the same chip & similar price. I'm just asking about features.

Answer (score 0):

The Quadro, Tesla and GRID cards are all using the exact same GPU as the GeForce cards.

See: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/hacking-nvidia-cards-into-their-professional-counterparts/

We know that some features such as Mosiac are just disabled via the driver, forcing the card to identify as a Quadro works with the Quadro drivers and enables the additional features.

What doesn't happen is the additional computing hardware is not enabled in the GPU, I would wager a bet that it is there, but there is some unknown strap to change to enable them that is yet to be discovered.

Also the Quadro cards are clocked slower then the GeForce cards as they favor stability over performance, and have ECC on the RAM.

Comment: That's what I think as well. ECC isn't present on all Quadros, though..and even clock speed is sometimes faster than GeForce(examples are mobile GTX 1070 and mobile Quadro P5000, of which the latter has a higher base clock speed). I just think that turbo boosting has more conservative steps.

I was just wondering if these features are actually fully available to use in Quadros, but just aren't marketed anywhere, because the target population doesn't care about them much...

Answer (score -1):

While I'm uncertain if this is true of the latest generations of  nVidia cards, previously Quadro cards had more attention paid to their output stages so that visual clarity was cleaner, and more powerful (many GeForce cards had weaker output, resulting in a darker, fuzzier image)

I would say, if you're interested in the best picture output, find a manufacturer who actually states their cables' impedance properties OR find a review that proved beyond a shadow of a doubt that the cable performs, correctly.  Or ask someone who works in graphics, professionally what they use.

Comment: You are not providing a solution to OP